# Value error in multiplying xarray variable with 2D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, python-xarray

```
import xarray as xr
xr.open_dataset(path_netcdf, chunks={'time': 10})
flow_data = hndl_tran['val']
new_arr = flow_data * vba
```

I get this error:

```
*** ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged
```

Here are the shapes of the 2 arrays:

```
flow_data.shape
(1165, 720, 1440)

vba.shape
(720L, 1440L)
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your numpy into an `xarray` object before you do the multiplication:

```
flow_data = xr.DataArray(hndl_tran['val'])
```

or vice versa

```
flow_data = np.array(flow_data)
```

Comment: please have a look at a corollary: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35593005/incorrect-shape-of-array-after-xarray-multiplication-operation

Comment: hmm no idea what's causing this, can you try it the other way around, converting the xarray to numpy array?

Comment: that wouldn't work, if i try to convert the xarray to numpy array, the resulting numpy array is too big to fit in memory. thanks for looking :)

Answer (score 1):

Building on @maxymoo's answer, you want to convert to a `DataArray`, *but also supply dims*, so operations with other arrays will work `flow_data = xr.DataArray(hndl_tran['val'], dims=['date', 'id'])`, replacing date & id with the appropriate names