# Incorrect shape of array after xarray multiplication operation

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, python-xarray

As per [Value error in multplying xarray variable with 2D numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35592074/value-error-in-multplying-xarray-variable-with-2d-numpy-array)

```
import xarray as xr
hndl_tran = xr.open_dataset(path_netcdf, chunks={'time': 10})
flow_data = hndl_tran['val']
new_arr = flow_data * xr.DataArray(vba)
```

Here are the shapes of input arrays

```
flow_data.shape
(1165, 720, 1440)

vba.shape
(720L, 1440L)
```

Here is the shape of the array after multiplying:

```
new_arr.shape
(1165, 720, 1440, 720, 1440)
```

I want the resulting array to have same shape as flow_data. How do i do this?

Comment: That `xr.DataArray()` might be doing some funny thing. So, to take more control over things and make sure broadcasting has the dims aligned, I think you could do `flow_data * (xr.DataArray(vba).reshape(720,1440))`.

Comment: thanks @Divakar, i get this error with reshape: `AttributeError: 'DataArray' object has no attribute 'reshape'`

Comment: Hmm, how about `np.reshape(xr.DataArray(vba),(720,1440))`?

Comment: hmm, i get this error with `np.resha[pe...`: `*** ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

xarray aligns the shapes based on the dimensions of the array. So if the dimensions don't share names, the multiplication is going to create a union of all dimensions.

I imagine `flow_data` and `vba` have differently named dimensions - use `.rename` to set matching dimensions to matching names

Comment: thanks @Maximilian, sorry for the late response. I am going to try out your answer and then accept.